# How can I connect a Logitech Pebble (M350) mouse via bluetooth?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I am trying to use a Logitech Pebble M350 mouse via bluetooth on XUbuntu 18.04.

When I run Xubuntu 18.04 from a live usb stick, the mouse connects perfectly. But when I try with the installed version it fails, as it failed with 16.04. The pairing and connection seem to fail?

Using the the bt device manager I discover and pair the mouse but am not given connection options, i.e. HID service connection. Further, the type of device is shown as unknown. The mouse light remains in pairing mode even after the BT device manager says it paired ok.

I see the following from the bluetoothctl

```
[Logitech Pebble]# info
Device C4:6C:8E:A3:57:34
    Name: Logitech Pebble
    Alias: Logitech Pebble
    Appearance: 0x03c2
    Icon: input-mouse
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d)
    Modalias: usb:v046DpB021d0007
[Logitech Pebble]# register-profile 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Unable to find GattManager proxy
Failed to pair: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
```

The pc is dual boot with Win0 and the mouse works perfectly under Win10.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance to the Ubuntu community!

Comment: FYI:  Xubuntu 16.04 was released in 2016-April (thus 16.04 with *year.month* format used) with 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-release/) so Xubuntu 16.04 is now EOL.  Use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm your actual status for your installed system.  Yes your Ubuntu base (or ubuntu server, ubuntu desktop with Unity desktop or Kylin desktop) has 5 years of support, but be aware all other flavors only had 3 years are now EOL. This is intended to be informational, and it's your choice for your use case (*security wise*).

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have since upgraded to 18.04 after testingg the bluetooth connection on a live usb stick. Although it worked perfectly on the live 18.04, the installed 18.04 still fails to connect the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

after rebooting a zillion times, and connecting on the Win10 boot, suddenly the same bt connection process worked and the mouse is now recognized.

I have no idea why it works now or why it did not work before but I think this subject can be closed.

Thanks for your help!
B